# Avoid table scan and use index instead in query

Tags: mysql, indexing, vitess

I am designing a new database and have noticed my queries are not scaling as well as they should be. When my aggregations involve hundreds of records I am seeing significant increases in response times. I am wondering if my query is deeply flawed or if I am just not using the right index.

I have done a lot of tweaking to my query but have not come up with a way to eliminate doing a full table scan and instead use an index. When I use a tool similar to `EXPLAIN` on my query I see the following:

- Full table scans are generally inefficient, avoid using them.
- Your query uses MySQL's 'filesort' operation. This tends to slow down queries.
- Your query uses MySQL's temporary tables. This can require extra I/O and tends to slow down queries.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `indexTable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col1` varbinary(320) NOT NULL,
  `col2` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `col3` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `metadata` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`userId`,`col1`,`col2`,`col3`),
  KEY `createdAt` (`createdAt`),
  KEY `id_userId_col1_col2_createdAt` (`id`,`userId`,`col1`,`col2`,`createdAt`),
  KEY `col1_col2_createdAt` (`col1`,`col2`,`createdAt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.userId, t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.metadata
FROM indexTable as t1
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT col1, col2, MAX(createdAt) AS maxCreatedAt
    FROM indexTable
    WHERE id = ? AND userId = ?
    GROUP BY col1, col2
    ORDER BY maxCreatedAt
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0) AS sub
ON t1.col1 = sub.col1
AND t1.col2 = sub.col2
AND t1.createdAt = sub.maxCreatedAt
WHERE t1.id = ? AND t1.userId = ?
ORDER BY t1.createdAt;
```

PK: `id, userId, col1, col2, col3`
Index: `createdAt`

Explain:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "34.50"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "cost_info": {
        "sort_cost": "10.00"
      },
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "sub",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 10,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "10.50",
              "eval_cost": "2.00",
              "prefix_cost": "12.50",
              "data_read_per_join": "3K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "col1",
              "col2",
              "maxCreatedAt"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`sub`.`maxCreatedAt` is not null)",
            "materialized_from_subquery": {
              "using_temporary_table": true,
              "dependent": false,
              "cacheable": true,
              "query_block": {
                "select_id": 2,
                "cost_info": {
                  "query_cost": "10.27"
                },
                "ordering_operation": {
                  "using_filesort": true,
                  "grouping_operation": {
                    "using_temporary_table": true,
                    "using_filesort": false,
                    "table": {
                      "table_name": "indexTable",
                      "access_type": "ref",
                      "possible_keys": [
                        "PRIMARY",
                        "createdAt",
                        "id_userId_col1_col2_createdAt",
                        "col1_col2_createdAt"
                      ],
                      "key": "PRIMARY",
                      "used_key_parts": [
                        "id",
                        "userId"
                      ],
                      "key_length": "8",
                      "ref": [
                        "const",
                        "const"
                      ],
                      "rows_examined_per_scan": 46,
                      "rows_produced_per_join": 46,
                      "filtered": "100.00",
                      "cost_info": {
                        "read_cost": "1.07",
                        "eval_cost": "9.20",
                        "prefix_cost": "10.27",
                        "data_read_per_join": "16K"
                      },
                      "used_columns": [
                        "id",
                        "userId",
                        "createdAt",
                        "col1",
                        "col2",
                        "col3"
                      ],
                      "attached_condition": "((`MyDB`.`indexTable`.`id` <=> 53) and (`MyDB`.`indexTable`.`userId` <=> 549814))"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "t1",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "createdAt",
              "id_userId_col1_col2_createdAt",
              "col1_col2_createdAt"
            ],
            "key": "id_userId_col1_col2_createdAt",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "id",
              "userId",
              "col1",
              "col2",
              "createdAt"
            ],
            "key_length": "339",
            "ref": [
              "const",
              "const",
              "sub.col1",
              "sub.col2",
              "sub.maxCreatedAt"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 10,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "10.00",
              "eval_cost": "2.00",
              "prefix_cost": "24.50",
              "data_read_per_join": "3K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "userId",
              "createdAt",
              "updatedAt",
              "col1",
              "col2",
              "col3",
              "metadata",
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query finds the most recent record in the grouping of `col1` and `col2`, orders by `createdAt`, and limits the entries to 10.

Comment: Try creating an index on `(id, userId, col1, col2, createdAt)`.

Comment: depending on how partitioned your data is, a composite index for `(id, userId,  createdAt)` also may work.

Comment: I tried the above indexes and didn't see any improvements. In fact the query seemed to perform slower.

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Did you try FORCE INDEX? sometimes MYSQL did not use indexes and use full table scan instead.

Answer (score 0):

The "derived" table (subquery) needs this composite index:

```
INDEX(id, userid,  -- in either order
      col1, col2,  -- in this order
      createdAt)   -- to make it "covering"
```

With that index, is *probably* will not do a full table scan.  However, it *will* involve a filesort.  This is because the `ORDER BY` is not the same as the `GROUP BY` and it is an aggregate.

`t1` needs

```
INDEX(col1, col2,  -- in either order
      createdAt)
```

`sub,maxCreatedAt` -- typo??

`ORDER BY t1.createdAt` -- another *necessary* filesort.

Do not beware of filesorts.  Especially when there are only 10 rows (as in the second case).

Without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I cannot say whether the "filesort" and the "temporary table" touched the disk at all, or was done in RAM.

`FORCE INDEX` is almost always a bad idea -- even if it helps today, it may hurt tomorrow.

The Optimizer will deliberately (and rightly) use a table scan if too much of the table needs to be looked at -- it is faster than bouncing between the index and the data.

Comment: Hey Rick thanks for the response. I just posted my EXPLAIN I hope that helps. I added the two indexes as you suggested but it looks like sql is deciding to not use them. Any thoughts other than forcing the index as you said is bad?

Comment: @rmw - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- there seem to be inconsistencies between your verbiage and the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I am obfuscating some column names as I want to keep them private. Hopefully it isn't too confusing i just tried to replace some column names with more generic ones.

Comment: This _may_ be a case where the Optimizer picks the wrong index from a choice.  What happens with `FORCE INDEX(id_userId_col1_col2_createdAt) on the _subquery_?

Comment: Even forcing the index didn't get it to work. I will post on how I solved this but thank you for the help your idexes should have worked!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by updating my query to include `id` and `userId` in the `GROUP BY`. I was then able to join on the two additional columns and for some reason that made MySQL use the right index.